# Why do knots and kinks appear in domestic Iron power cords?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life, inductance

Our domestic steam clothing Iron has a rating of 2400W, and the house supply supply is 220V.

[image]

After about three months of use, the heavily cloth braided power cord of a new iron develops kinks, which are impossible to manually flatten.

I obviously realise that the power demand is comparatively high, and that once a kink starts to occurs there is an inductance effect. This is also related to the fact that the braiding at the kink also wears away rapidly, leaving the three power wires exposed, within their plastic coating.

My reasoning is that, in that time, the new cord develops a weak spot which is then pulled in tighter by the magnetic field.

The "paradox" for me is that my vacuum cleaner, with pretty much the same power demand but a much longer, plastic covered cable, never exhibits this behavior.

I don't want to ask a confirmatory type  question, but  it's been quite a while since I self-studied electromagnetic theory and I have no idea regarding basic electrical engineering principles, apologies.

So is the distortion caused by a completely short power run, allowing coils to develop, then the heavy cloth braiding causes a discontinuity in the cord and this  allows a self inductance effect to more easily occur, creating the kink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by  @tfb, my own short answer to this is to contradict my electromagnetic  musings in my question and say that,  as Iron manufacturers know that hot metal plates can easily burn power cable insulation,  the price you pay for safety is a heavy cord, and that once it develops a kink, it retains it.